# Mac os: Rails broken - bundle not working - ovirt-engine-sdk - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ovirt

I'm trying to use ovirt-engine-sdk gem in my rails(6) application. bundle install is failing in my mac machine.
As per the PR's the gem should work with ruby 3.x versions but i'm getting following error when i do bundle install

```
Installing ovirt-engine-sdk 4.6.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/ext/ovirtsdk4c
/Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby -I /Users/sh077503/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20240306-89931-47eohb.rb extconf.rb
checking for xml2-config... yes
checking for curl-config... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/ext/ovirtsdk4c
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/ext/ovirtsdk4c
make "DESTDIR="
compiling ov_error.c
compiling ov_http_client.c
ov_http_client.c:216:29: warning: excess elements in array initializer [-Wexcess-initializers]
        .reserved = { NULL, NULL }
                            ^~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
               ^~~~~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:501:9: error: call to undeclared function 'ruby_thread_has_gvl_p'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (ruby_thread_has_gvl_p()) {
        ^
ov_http_client.c:853:25: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'CURLMcode' to different enumeration type 'CURLcode' [-Wenum-conversion]
    context_ptr->code = curl_multi_wait(context_ptr->handle, NULL, 0, timeout, NULL);
                      ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:874:25: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'CURLMcode' to different enumeration type 'CURLcode' [-Wenum-conversion]
    context_ptr->code = curl_multi_perform(context_ptr->handle, &pending);
                      ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:1009:47: warning: incompatible function pointer types passing 'int (VALUE, VALUE, struct curl_slist **)' (aka 'int (unsigned long, unsigned long, struct curl_slist **)')
to parameter of type 'int (*)(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)' (aka 'int (*)(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)') [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
        rb_hash_foreach(request_ptr->headers, ov_http_client_add_header, (VALUE) headers);
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sh077503/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/intern/hash.h:33:35: note: passing argument to parameter here
void rb_hash_foreach(VALUE, int (*)(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE), VALUE);
                                  ^
4 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [ov_http_client.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

How can i install/integrate ovirt-engine-sdk in my rails application? Thanks in advance for any help. Please let me know if there are any other files or information you need to assist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [client.c:178:24: error: call to undeclared function 'rb\_tainted\_str\_new2'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77799851/client-c17824-error-call-to-undeclared-function-rb-tainted-str-new2-iso-c)

Comment: @MikeSzyndel This worked for me. Thanks for your help.  does avoiding the error related to implicit function declaration cause any issues in ovirt-engine-sdk operations.?

Comment: It should not. It’s just a strict compiler setting on macOS

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem to this. I ran

`gem install ovirt-engine-sdk -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration”`

followed by

`bundle install`

and everything worked.